# How to rewrite URLs in PHP using .htaccess, I have tried it but it's not working?

Tags: url-rewriting, dynamic-url

can anyone please help me to rewrite url in php...
http://localhost:81/cabnotels/Domestic-tours/tour.php?Delhi&india%27s-golden-triangle-tour&type=tour&id=19

This is the current URL and I want to rewrite as..
http://localhost:81/cabnotels/Domestic-tours/tour/Delhi/india's-golden-triangle-tour/tour/19

Please help..
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share the code you tried, we're here to help, not to write code for you :)

Also make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your installation

Comment: And please don’t tag all over the place. This question has very little to do with `javascript` or `phpmyadmin`, and even for tagging `php` there is no real good reason here so far (tags removed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use comma in your url like you have in (india's) and you can rewrite your url using the htaccess like:

```
RewriteRule ^cabnotels/domestic-tours/tours/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/tour/([^/]*)$ tour.php?$1&$2&$3&$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

OR Simply if you have only one URL:

```
RewriteRule ^cabnotels/Domestic-tours/tour/Delhi/indias-golden-triangle-tour/tour/19$ cabnotels/Domestic-tours/tour.php?Delhi&india%27s-golden-triangle-tour&type=tour&id=19
```

Comment: I have used this --- RewriteRule ^cabnotels/domestic-tours/tour/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/tour/([^/]*)$ tour.php?$1&$2&$3&$4 [QSA,L,NC] but it's not working, I removed the india's also and simply added india, It's a dynamic page.